# Genymotion and Virtual box

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine, genymotion

I keep geting this error from Virtual Box that I don’t have enough memory to launch the emulator for Genymotion to display my apps from android studio. Is there an emulator that takes up less space or anything to recommend to fix the problem?

Comment: What are your system config? i.e RAM available.

Comment: You haven't really provided us with enough information to help you. Perhaps you could describe your system setup in a bit more detail...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give more space to guest OS.